# user input validation: date input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a method below which asks user to provide date from they keyboard, I need to extend my code to validate if user indeed entered the data in format M/d/yyyy.
If not, ask again to repeat and correct input data, how can I implement that?

```
    private static void extracted2(Doctor l1, Patient p1, List<Schedule> lista) {
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("provide data with format M/d/yyyy");

    while (true) {
        try {
            String userinput = sc2.next();
            DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(userinput, dateFormat);
            Schedule g5 = new Schedule(5, l1, p1, date, false, false);
            lista.add(g5);
            for (Schedule x : lista) {
                System.out.println(x);
            }

        } catch (DataFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong data " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: capture the DateFormatException in try catch and ask again

Comment: I modified my code my but DataFormatException is underscored red with error: Unreachable catch block for DataFormatException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Comment: Do you want user prompt  keeps coming for invalid input until user enters valid input?

Comment: I have just updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are close but here is the final solution:
Removed other logic from the code since it can be added.

```
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        LocalDate date = null;
        boolean isValid;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Provide date format M/d/yyyy");
                DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");
                String userinput = sc2.next();
                date = LocalDate.parse(userinput, dateFormat);
                isValid = true;
            } catch (DateTimeParseException exception) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        } while(!isValid);
System.out.println(date);
```

output:

> ```
> Provide date format M/d/yyyy
> 333
> Provide date format M/d/yyyy
> 444
> Provide date format M/d/yyyy
> 1/2/2020
> 2020-01-02
> ```